# Angular SSR is not working with docker NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, server-side-rendering, angular-ssr

I added angualr universal to my app.

SSR rendering works fine.

But when I run my app in docker SSR working without nginx
but i need ssr work with nginx

This is my docker file:

```html
FROM <dockerhubrepo>/ubuntu_node_v18:latest AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json /app/

RUN npm install mime@latest
RUN npm install -f
COPY . .
# this will build the browser and server files:
RUN npm run build-testing:ssr
FROM  <dockerhubrepo>/nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
RUN ls /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY --from=build /app/nginx/cliffwebsite_testing.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

FROM immersionslabs/ubuntu_node_v18:latest AS ssr-server
COPY --from=build /app/dist /app/dist/
RUN ls /app/dist/
COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:ssr"]
```

This is my Nginx conf file:

```html
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

then i run the command

```html
docker build -t <image-name> .
```

After building Image am running the docker image:

```html
docker run -d -p 4000:4000 <docker-image-id>
```

it will run local but I find an error

**nginx not found**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.